# CrashReporter, missing required architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, x86-64, crash-reports

I am trying to compile my app on the news iOS beta but I bounce in an error in the CrashReporter. The compilers report the missing architecture x86_64 when trying to compile for 64 bits. I looked at the crashreporter file PLCrashReportSystemInfo.h and in the typedef enum PLCrashReportArchitectureX86_64 seems to be there with value 1. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The new library on the .git repository seems to be updated for 64 bits. AT least I add no errors after having replaced it.